# Windows Server in UTC, need Task Scheduler to shift tasks with summer time

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler, timezone

I'm perfectly happy to have my server in UTC, but when a user needs something scheduled to happen in a particular time in a particular time zone, they are expecting that to obey their time zone rules as they change time zones throughout the year (I'm not trying to accommodate geographic movement).

Is there a way to easily accommodate this without changing the server to switch time zones twice a year or do you have to have two tasks set up for the different time zones as the users' perception changes from EDT to EST?

It seems like this would be a useful feature since on non-UTC servers, they offer the reverse option to specify a time in UTC for the task to be able to synchronize tasks on different servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no easy way. That is the price for you being "totally happy to have the server in UTC". The server now runs in UTC. Be happy with it.

Comment: OK, please see my follow-on question, then: http://serverfault.com/questions/479712/toggling-enabled-disabled-on-specific-triggers-in-a-task-in-the-task-scheduler-u